# Send email using java without JavaMail

Tags: java, sockets, smtp

I want to write a socket program to send a SMTP email, without using any JavaMail API. I found code on the Internet to do that, but it doesn't work correctly.
Here's the program:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class SMTPTest
{ public static void main(String[] args)
{ SMTPTest smtp = new SMTPTest();
smtp.sendMail();
}

public void sendMail()
{
try
{
Socket s = new Socket("smtp.gmail.com", 465); 
out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
in = new BufferedReader(new
InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
String hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
System.out.println("hostName = " + hostName);
send(null);
send("HELO " + hostName);
send("MAIL FROM: " + "my email@gmail.com");
send("RCPT TO: " + "my email@gmail.com");
send("DATA");
send("Happy SMTP Programming!!");
send("Happy SMTP Programming!!");
send(".");
send("QUIT");
s.close();
out.close();
in.close();
}
catch(IOException e)
{ e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public void send(String s) throws IOException
{ if (s != null)
{ out.println(s);
out.flush();
}
String line;
if ((line = in.readLine()) != null) //output the response
System.out.println(line);
}

private PrintWriter out;
private BufferedReader in;
}
```

Can anyone can help?
Here is the error:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at SMTPTest.sendMail(SMTPTest.java:19)
at SMTPTest.main(SMTPTest.java:12)
```

Comment: Unknow host exception means that somehow Java cannot reach the Internet Connection (more exactly the DNS servers). Firewall issue?

Comment: You _cannot_ use Google mail servers with plain SMTP - they need TLS.  Use another smtp server.

Comment: If you want directly to send to gmail account, then you need to figure DNS MX type records for gmail.com, and then you can try to connect to it using your code. If you want to use Google smtp as MTA, then you need to !) use SSL connection, 2) authenticate yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot use Google mail servers with plain SMTP - they need TLS.

Not sure if this will help, but I've seen this statement in some code examples:

```
System.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
Socket s = new Socket(...);
```

Comment: That is a JavaMail property which is not being used here.  See http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Socket, use SSLSocket, like so:

```
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) ((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()).createSocket(InetAddress.getByName("smtp.gmail.com"), 465);
```

You'll have to catch the exception, but you get the idea.