# SMTP socket -- Authentocation & SSLSocket

Tags: sockets, authentication, ssl, smtp, sslsocketfactory

I am looking into SMTP socket for experiment and coded [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236224/send-email-using-java-without-javamail) sample.

The code is making the connection with the server (I'm connecting to smtp of gmail).

During the connection, I'm receiving the following messages from the server. (In the line-comments are the stream sent that caused the message from the server.)

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP qw8sm31710864pbb.27 - gsmtp   // EHLO MY-HOSTNAME
250-mx.google.com at your service, [184.6.159.254]  // STARTTLS
250-8BITMIME   // MAIL From: myName <xyz@gmail.com>
250-SIZE 35882577    //  RCPT To: destName <pqr@hotmail.com>
250-STARTTLS // DATA
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES // Subject: subjectline here
250 CHUNKING // .
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS // QUIT
```

The messages from the server are telling that nothing is going wrong with the connection and the data sent(?) However, the server is dropping the request-- I`m not seeing the message at pqr@hotmail.com.

1.) In this and some other examples I've looked at, I've seen no trace of authentication-- the password doesn't appear anywhere, not even a word of it. How is this supposed to work without authentication? The samples I've seen each sound like authentication isn't an issue. With this, anyone can email out from anyone's account.

2.)  The [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236224/send-email-using-java-without-javamail) is suggested to use SSLSocket. The ones in [findJar](http://www.findjar.com/) are each coming in with 
some browser add-ons and some other packages. isn't there a way to get around this-- I'm only looking to get the sslSocket itself.

I'm new to these here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servers usually require some form of authentication but normally at a minimum will at least ensure that you are sending from the domain that you say you are sending from (by checking your IP address against the domain and also verifying that the domain is allowed). A lot of work has been done to prevent spammers from sending email on open email hosts.

Part of your problem is that you are sending SMTP commands when the mail server (MTA - mail transfer agent) is expecting you to be negotiating an SSL session. You might try using something like tcpdump or wireshark to examine an actual session.

If C is client and S is server then normally you would have:

```
C - connect to server
S - shows SMTP prompt with a 2xx series prefix
C - send ELHO (or HELO for less capable servers)
S - should respond with a 2xx series of messages with capabilities one per line if your domain is ok
C - send STARTTLS
S - response with 2xx series message
```

at this point you have to negotiate the TLS connection
and after that is negotiated you can then start sending commands
across that connection.  Your code has to be written to handle the negotiation
and switch to TLS as it won't be automatically handled. if you don't your subsequent
commands will basically be treated as gibberish and ignored by the server.  In essence,
sending the subsequent SMTP commands will look like incorrect responses to the
TLS negotiation session.

There is a bit more info at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STARTTLS with some pointers.
SMTP can be fairly complex so unless you are connecting to a specific system it is probably
best to use something like JavaMail to communicate with MTAs.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation of the server messages is completly wrong:

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP qw8sm31710864pbb.27 - gsmtp
```

this is the welcome message you get after connect, e.g. without sending any data.

```
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 35882577 
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 CHUNKING
```

This is the multi-line response you get back at your EHLO command.

```
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
```

This is the message you get in response to your STARTTLS command.

As you can see, the server did not even start to process your MAIL FROM, RCPT TO and DATA so it is no wonder the mail did not get sent. I think you should make yourself more familiar with the SMTP protocol before attempting to use it.